# How to manage asynchronous properly

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

my code outputs everytime different numbers. Is this a proper way I am using it?
Here is the code:

```
export class GetPlanetsService {
  url='https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=';
  planets:Planet[]=[];
  headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Accept', 'application/json');

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  getPlanet(pageIndex){                                          
    return this.http.get<Planets>(`${this.url}${pageIndex}`,{headers:this.headers});
  }
  getAllPlanets(){
    let numberOfPages=7;  // Tried to do it dynamically but got infinite loop
    for(let j=1;j<=numberOfPages;j++){
      this.getPlanet(j).subscribe(value=>{
        for(let i=0;i<value.results.length;i++){
          this.planets.push(value.results[i]);
          if(j==numberOfPages && i==(value.results.length-1)){
            console.log(this.planets);  //There is outputted everytime different number
          }
        }     

    });

    }
  }
```

Have you got any tips and could you explain it in simple words?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` for this, Dont forget to include

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
```

> forkJoin waits for each HTTP request to complete and group’s all the
>   observables returned by each HTTP call into a single observable array
>   and finally return that observable array.

```
getPlanet(pageIndex) {
        return this.http.get < Planets > (`${this.url}${pageIndex}`, {
            headers: this.headers
        });
    }

    getAllPlanets() {
        const response = [...Array(7).keys()].map(i => this.getPlanet(i));
        return forkJoin(response);
    }
```

in your component you can call `getAllPlanets`

```
this.getPlanetsService.getAllPlanets()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);

 });
```

Comment: What does it mean?
[...Array(7).keys()]

Comment: basically it is a  Spread syntax ..., The Array() constructor , so we have create a Array with empty slots 7. Spread syntax allows an iterable and the The keys() method returns a new Array Iterator object that contains the keys for each index in the array. so it will return the array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can control your async behavior.

1. [Promises.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
2. [Async Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
3. [Async library](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is deeper problemes here.

First, why are you trying to call the server 7 times in a row? What if I want page 200? You will make 200 Http requests? The server should return the entire list. It will increase performance and reduce complexity on client side.

Also, why `getAllPlanets()` return `void`? It's not intuitive. Instead, `getAllPlanets()` should return `Observable<Planet[]>`. All functions should either return of modify (it's part of the CQS principle) here the purpose it to return data so you can't notify your object state e.g. `this.planets.push(value.results[i])`. What if a invoke the function twice? Then, `this.planets` will contain the result of both requests.